# Can't install ROS due to malformed entry in sources (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Tags: ros

I'm trying to install ROS and can't because:

```
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

What do I do?

History:

```
 1  sudo apt update
 2  sudo apt upgrade
 3  sudo apt update
 4  sudo apt install bpython
 5  bpython
 6  sudo apt install x11-apps
 7  xeyes &
 8  xcalc
 9  sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
10  sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu
11  (lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
12  sudo apt install curl # if you haven't already installed curl
13  sudo apt install curl
14  sudo apt update
15  sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full
16  cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
17  sudo add-apt-repository universe
18  sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
19  sudo apt update
20  sudo add-apt-repository universe
21  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
22  history
```

Request 1:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu
(lsb_release -sc) main
```

Comment: Which version of  Ubuntu are you running? What is inside the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list `? Add these information [inside the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1467234/edit). List all the steps you did to install ROS by copying and pasting the `history` of commands from the terminal into the question. Indicate at which step you get this error.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: $ /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
-bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list: Permission denied

Comment: Enter `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list` and add the output in your question. Format the pasted output as `code` by using the {_} icon above the edit window.

Comment: Oh, no! I'm going to have to do this again?? Thank you, for the information.

Answer (score 2):

These lines in the `.list` file

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu
(lsb_release -sc) main
```

should be one line like this

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic main
```